# jquery multiple selects disable/enable options

Tags: jquery, html

I have three identical drop down menus with three options.

Each one can only be chosen once in one menu and then the selected option should be disabled in all the other selected menus.

I have a problem enabling the options once the empty option (`""`) is chosen again (selection cleared). However placing `$(this).attr('disabled','');` in the change event does seem to work.

How can this be done?

```js
$('.e1').change(function() {
  var value = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
  if (value != '') {
    $('#myselects').find('option:not(:selected)').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() == value) {

        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

      }
    });
  }

})
```

```html
<div id="myselects">
  <select class="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option></option>
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Amalapuram</option>
    <option>Anakapalli</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to check out the $(this).prop('disabled', false) method instead, which (if I can recall correctly) is the preferred method to use when disabling/enabling elements.

Answer (score 0):

try using `$(this).prop('disabled',true);` per

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes that have not been set. **To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method.**
>   http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).removeAttr('disabled');`

Answer (score 0):

The problem were the conditions and the selectors. This should be what you asked for (press run):

```js
$('.e1').change(function() {
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  $('p').text("Last selected: " + selectedVal)
  if (selectedVal !== '')
    $('#myselects').find('select>option:not(:first-of-type)').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === selectedVal)
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    });
  else 
    $('#myselects').find('select>option').each(function() {
      $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myselects">
  <select class="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option></option>
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Amalapuram</option>
    <option>Anakapalli</option>
  </select>
  <select class="e1" style="width:300px">
    <option></option>
    <option>Alabama</option>
    <option>Amalapuram</option>
    <option>Anakapalli</option>
    <option>anana</option>
  </select>
</div>
<p></p>
```

I also used the `prop` method, it's better because «`.attr()` method returns `undefined` for attributes that have not been set» as [Jhony mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30684726/1326147)...

Comment: Thanks, this has a bug I am still able to choose two of the same options when I choose the blank option after selecting both

Comment: @user2382789 Hi again, the behavior I understood from your question was that the blank `option` would deselect all the `options` in all the `selects`, but then, since you mentioned it as a bug, I thought you may only want to re-enable the `option` that was disabled from the current `select` and leave all the others selected in other `selects` disabled. This is more complex and requires an array with all the currently selected `options` and also a detection of the current state when you focus on a particular `select`. However, if this is the behavior, you may not need a blank `option` at all.

Comment: At the end of all of it the user is not supposed to be able to choose the same option more than once